# Como verificar se a consulta não retornou dados?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma consulta é gostaria de saber se a mesma retornou dados.

```
//classe aplicação-
private List<tb_cabecalho> TransformaReaderEmListaObjetos(SqlDataReader reader)
{
    var retornando = new List<tb_cabecalho>();
    while (reader.Read())
    {

        tb_cabecalho tabela = new tb_cabecalho()
        {
            campofixo = "H",
            cnpjdoecomerce = "61549259000180",
            dataincial = reader["DataInicial"] == DBNull.Value ? DateTime.MinValue : Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DataInicial"]),
            datafinal = reader["DataFinal"] == DBNull.Value ? DateTime.MinValue : Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DataFinal"])
        };

        retornando.Add(tabela);
    }
    reader.Close();
    return retornando;
}

    /// <summary>
    /// Aqui estou retornando os dados do cabecalho
    /// </summary>
    var tbuscar = new cabecalhoAplicacao();
    var retorno = tbuscar.DadosDoCabecalho();
```

Comment: Você quer testar dentro do metodo TransformaReaderEmListaObjetos testando ou quer testar o retorno dele?

Comment: Quero verificar se o TransformaReaderEmListaObjetos  está retornando os dados porque se vim vazio vai gera um erro

Comment: A resposta do GOKU SSJGod lhe atende.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você quer verificar se seu método esta retornando valor, o mais simples a fazer nesse caso é usar o um `if lista == null` é um [Count()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3(v=vs.110).aspx) `> 0.`

```
List<tb_cabecalho> lista = TransformaReaderEmListaObjetos(reader);
if(lista != null && lista.Count > 0)
{
   // Todo... 
}
```

Ou simplesmente use o [Any()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb337697(v=vs.90).aspx)

```
if(lista.Any())
{
   // Todo... 
}
```

Comment: Por favor, se **`lista`** realmente for um **`List`**, use a propriedade **`Count`** ao invés do método **`Count()`**.

Comment: Eu espero que seja realmente um list

Comment: Só como dica, você pode usar `lista?.Any()` ao invés de verificar se o objeto é nulo e a propriedade `Count`

Comment: Também é uma boa dica

Comment: agradeço a ajuda de todos

Answer (score 0):

Você pode verificar se sua consulta retornou alguma linha:

```
if(!reader.HasRow) return null;
```

Do outro lado, aonde você consome o método, basta verificar se o retorno é diferente de `null`. Você deve fazer essa verificação antes do `while`

Comment: Amigo, você verificou isso: var retornando = new List<tb_cabecalho>();

Comment: poderia melhorar a resposta

Comment: var retornando = new List<tb_cabecalho>(); isso apenas cria uma lista de objetos 'tb_cabecalho' Agora para saber se a consulta SqlDataReader tem resultado, basta usar o código citado. Porém você pode verificar se a lista tem items. if(retornado.Count > 0) return null;